# How do I fix this "TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'method'" Error?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science

I've tried to use the imputer to replace all of the NaN portions of my database with the averages of its respectful column. For example, I wanted to fix a blank entry in my database under the salary column and I want that blank section to be filled with the average salary values under that column. I tried doing this by following along with a tutorial but I think the video was outdated, resulting in this error.
 Code:

```
#Data Proccesing 

#Importing the Libaries 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset 
dataset = pd.read_csv("Data.csv") 
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 3].values 

#Taking care of Missig Data 
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer 
#The source of all the problems
imputer = Imputer(missing_values = 'NaN', strategy = 'mean', axis = 0)
imputer = imputer.fit(X[:, 1:3]) 
X[:, 1:3] = imputer.transform
```

Initially, X looked like this when compiled prior to using Imputer:[image: X prior to Imputer]

However, Once I compiled lines 16-18, I got this error and I'm not sure what to do [image: The "TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'method'" Error]

Comment: The error explains exactly how to solve the issue. `float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'method'`. To help diagnose, you can split your code and use the `type` function to validate the types.

Comment: Please also do not post terminal/code output in images. Please see here for why: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/40481

Comment: Thank you and I will refrain from doing that from now on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
imputer.transform
```

Should be

```
imputer.transform()
```

...With parentheses to actually call the method rather than assign it's name to something.

Comment: Should I type imputer.transform() or imputer.transform(X[:, 1:3])?

Comment: The latter, I believe . Try them out yourself and see which one has the desired result.

Comment: Oh my god! It actually worked! Thank you so much,  you really helped me out in a time where I felt as if I had no one to turn to.

Comment: That's what we're here for! Please mark this answer as accepted if it works - so other users with similar problems can be helped too :)